# Запись битов из массива vector<bool> в файл (C++)

Tags: c++

Как записать биты из vector типа `bool` в файл. Пробовал всячески, ничего не помогло. Пишет что должен быть типа `char`, но мне необходимо именно `bool`.

Comment: Именно биты, не байты?

Comment: Код ваш покажите.

Comment: Можно вот так например: std::copy(v.begin(), v.end(), std::ostreambuf_iterator<char>(f)); (1 байт файла на 1 бит исходного массива).

Comment: И все таки уточните, у вас `BOOL` или `bool`, это может вводить в заблуждение (тоже и для `CHAR`).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian, вангую следующий вопрос: как считать массив битов из файла с байтами :)

Comment: @PinkTux ну это уже второй (отдельный) вопрос ))

Comment: И как вы видите запись всего трех битов в файл?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов если файловая система поддерживает, то почему нет?

Comment: да. именно биты. тип bool , char, не понимаю, почему капс не выключил. проблема в том, что необходимо побитово считывать массив и загонять 8 бит в char, и так до конца

Comment: Собирайте `char`-ы из ваших бит (по 8 штук) и пишите в файл.

Comment: Какой длины у вас вектор? Эта длина фиксирована?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian а какая из ФС поддерживает запись трех битов в файл? И, заодно, какая ОС. WriteFile в винде пишет только байтами, например.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов честно говоря не в курсе, просто не вижу принципиального ограничения. А на практике да, наверное везде минимум по байту пишут.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian я вижу принципиальное ограничение в том, что файл не может быть меньше 1 байта, файлы выровнены на 1 байт. И запись трех битов в файл, я считаю, невозможна.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов ну и почему же не может быть? Ну и заодно может подскажите, почему именно цифру восемь выбрали для минимального/кратного размера.

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Примера ФС/ОС с файлами меньше 1 байта вы не привели. Я о таком тоже не знаю, поэтому считаю что в текущих реалиях такое невозможно.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы увидили "принципиальное ограничение" (основываясь только на том, что не знаете такие ФС/ОС), почему же мне предлагаете какие то примеры искать? Подумайте, что мешает вам написать поддержку такой системы например для linux.

Answer (score 2):

Байт - минимальный независимо адресуемый набор данных. Бит может существовать только в составе какого-то байта. Соответственно, в языке невозможна адресация одного бита. `vector<bool>` - прокси, который просто делает вид, что работает с отдельными битами, но на самом деле биты, с которыми он работает, входят в состав байтов.

Так что вопрос так, как он сформулирован, просто бессмысленен. Вы можете записывать биты в составе байтов, - от 1 до 8 (не будем вдаваться в экзотику) бит в одном байте.

Если же вас интересует вопрос, как записать весь вектор сразу, не деля его на отдельные биты, то спрашивать надо несколько иначе, так что я даже не уверен, что именно вас интересует. Но отвечу и на это.

В этом случае проблема в том, что стандарт, насколько я знаю, не требует того или иного конкретного решения от реализации, а значит, нет и переносимого способа достучаться до байтов с интересующими вас битами. В VC++ это, например, тип `unsigned int`, а не `char` или что-то еще однобайтное. В лучшем случае надо лезть внутрь исходников и докапываться, где именно и как они там хранятся. Причем не факт, что этот "лучший" случай на самом деле не худший :( Плюс - с очень высокой вероятностью - вас просто никто не допустит непосредственно к этим данным в силу того, что они и их интерфейс будут `private`.

Comment: **Байт - минимальный независимо адресуемый набор данных.** - что мешает адресовать 7 бит например? (история знает примеры)

Comment: Только вы вот забыли про std::bitset

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Я же написал - **(не будем вдаваться в экзотику)** Кстати, зайдите на Википедию и измените определение байта, а то они там не знают, что это можно - адресовать 7 бит при восьмибитном байте...

Comment: @gbg или ещё лучше `boost::dynamic_bitset` (вдруг понадобится динамически забивать)

Comment: @gbg Мне казалось, что вопрос о `vector<bool>`. Наверное, я ошибся.

Comment: @Harry, автор пытается бриться миской. Я предлагаю ему воспользоваться таки бритвой - вдруг, удобнее будет.
А вам я замечаю, что в C++ есть стандартное средство для работы с отдельными битами, причем не единственное.

Comment: @gbg Ну вот вы и предложили. Я, в рамках заданного вопроса, пояснил, почему миской неудобно :)

Comment: @Harry не понял юмора на счет википедии. Если мы говорим только о языке C, то да, минимальный размер char это 8 бит, и все остальные типы должны быть кратными ему. Что впрочем не отменяет возможность иметь 9-ти битный char (и 36 битный long).

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Байт - это минимальная адресуемая единица памяти. Все. Вы возражаете - нет, адресовать можно 7 бит. Если бы вы говорили, что байт может быть 7-битовым, 32-битовым или однобитовым - я бу не спорил. Но ваше заявление по сути звучит так: байт может быть БОЛЬШЕ, чем минимальный адресуемый участок памяти. Если это так - надо исправить определение байта в той же Википедии, где байт определен так, как я написал.

Comment: @Harry Допустим, у вас есть 4-х битная микросхема памяти, и каждый адрес хранит только 4 бита, что тогда?

Comment: @VladimirGamalian Тогда в этой архитектуре 1 байт == 4 бита

Comment: @Harry все, я здаюсь )) Даже не буду думать о ситуации 1 байт == 1 бит

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42868/discussion-between-vladimir-gamalian-and-harry).